# Spring Social for Facebook - get user location

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-social

I am using spring social Facebook to connect to facebook. The connection works well. I am trying to get the user's location with the following code:

```
FacebookProfile profile = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile();
Reference rLocation = profile.getLocation();
Location location= facebook.fetchObject(rLocation.getId(), Location.class);
```

But what I get is an empty location object (it doesn't have any of the details). I can see that the rLocation does have a name (Los Angeles) but I also need the country.

Any idea how to get the actual Location object?

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the location details that are a part of the Reference object which is the rLocation here. You can get the location city and location state but the location country is not a part of the Reference object.

```
    Reference rLocation = profile.getLocation();
    String locationName = rLocation.getName(); 
    String[] cityAndState = locationName.split(",");
    String city = cityAndState[0].trim();
    String state = cityAndState[1].trim();
```

The Location object basically helps to get the details of a user checked in location in facebook. Please refer to the spring social facebook API for more details.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/social/facebook/api/Location.html

Comment: Unfortunately not all the places follow this convention and some of them include in the name only the city, not the country too.