# Location not populated on Spring Social Facebook

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I'm trying to get user location in Spring Social Facebook:

```
Facebook fb = ((Facebook) connection.getApi());
Page pg = fb.pageOperations().getPage(fb.userOperations().getUserProfile().getLocation().getId());
```

The problem is that `pg.getLocation()` returns `null`.

I also tried with

```
fb.fetchObject(fb.userOperations().getUserProfile().getLocation().getId(), org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Location.class)
```

but it does populate only the name, not country or other fields.

Trying on Graph API Explorer [/v2.6/112286918797929?fields=id,name,location](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=112286918797929%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Clocation&version=v2.6) returns as expected:

```
{
  "id": "112286918797929",
  "name": "Sacele",
  "location": {
    "city": "Sacele",
    "country": "Romania",
    "latitude": 45.6167,
    "longitude": 25.6833
  }
}
```

Is this an issue with Spring Social Facebook?

I'm using Spring Social 1.1.4 and Spring Social Facebook 2.0.3.

I also tried [Spring Social for Facebook - get user location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591797/spring-social-for-facebook-get-user-location), but unfortunately not all the places follow the name convention *City, Country* and some of them include in the name only the city, not the country too. Plus how can you get the geo-coordinates?

Comment: I guess it could be for the URL that spring social is using to get permission from the user... but not so sure.

Comment: I added `user_location` permission. What URL are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it. First of all it doesn't work with `PageOperations`, but it works with `GraphApi`.

And the code is

```
UserProfile userProfile = fb.userOperations().getUserProfile();
Page pg = fb.fetchObject(userProfile.getLocation().getId(), Page.class, "location");
```

The trick is specifying the third parameter, which represents the fields (you can specify multiple fields as strings). Now the page is populated and you can get the country like `pg.getLocation().getCountry()`.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that, the following command

```
fb.fetchObject(fb.userOperations().getUserProfile().getLocation().getId(), org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Location.class)
```

gives response the name which is from Reference.

That's have 2 public methods: `getId()` and `getName()`.

Some methods like `getLocation()` is depends on permission. If any user gives you permission to see his location, then you can access this method.

[From documentation:](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/facebook/api/FacebookProfile.html#getLocation())

> **getLocation**
>
> public Reference getLocation()
>
> The user's location. Available only with "user_location" or "friends_location" permission.
>
> Returns: a
>   Reference to the user's location, if available

### Code Sample:

```
  Page profile=facebookTemplate.pageOperations().getPage(id);
  String name=profile.getName();
  String webside=profile.getWebsite();
  String logo="http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture";
  party=new FullPoliticalParty(name,color,logo,webside);
  String phone=profile.getPhone() == null ? "No disponible" : profile.getPhone();
  party.setPhone(phone);
  org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Location loc=profile.getLocation();
  if (loc != null) {
    location=new LocationMapa(loc.getCity(),loc.getCountry(),loc.getStreet(),loc.getZip());
  }
  party.setLocation(location);
```

### Resource Link:

1. [Location class](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/facebook/api/Location.html)
2. [Java Code Examples for
   org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Page](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Page)

---

---

### UPDATE1:

I think you need user permissions through Graph API. Then you can access location or other info that you requested from specific user. `Checking Current Permissions` and `Handling Missing Permissions` is given in [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking).

### For USER permissions:

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{user-id}/permissions",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

For user permissions, you can go through [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions)

For user location, you can go through [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_location).

After getting related permission, you can get access location, longitude, latitude and other info also.

Comment: I already read the documentation, but my problem was that it doesn't work.

First of all your code does not compile because `fb.userOperations().getUserProfile().getLocation()` is of type `Reference` which does have none of the methods above, except `getId()`.

If you want something of `Location` type, you should do as I stated in my question, but then `getCountry()` returns null, as I also stated above.

Comment: And I also mentioned that I'm using Spring Social 1.1.4, which is in fact the latest stable release.

Comment: @AdrianBer Sorry for misunderstanding. Please have a look updated.

Comment: Again, I read the documentation. But my problem is that all the fields in `Location` are null, except `id` and `name`.

Comment: @AdrianBer I have updated and given the policy how to get permission through api. Then you can access your user granted info. Thanks

Comment: I have `user_location` permission, but it still doesn't work.